# Returning the column names used in Query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am working with a tool that connects to PostgreSQL, which returns the result of a query in a multi-dimensional array, but, I need the name of the columns used in the query, is there any way to return this information too, automatically, without having to modify it existing queries?

I have the possibility to concatenate codes in the existing queries, but not to change them.

an idea, would be to return the name of the columns in the first row of the query result, this row I would eliminate within the program....

Assuming I have the following query:

```
SELECT
   A.USER_ID    AS ID
   A.USER_NAME  AS NAME
   A.AGE
FROM USERS A
```

the result could be something like:

```
1º row -> | ID | NAME | AGE |
2º row -> | 2  | JOHN | 25  |
3º row -> ....
```

of course, this is just an idea ...

Comment: How you do this using "a tool" depends on what that tool is.  Please add a tag for it.

Comment: this tool is a SQLRDD for the Harbour Compiler...

Comment: You should edit that into the question